# Find the coordinates in terms of $r$ of the point $T$ on segment $PQ$ such that $\frac{PT}{PQ} = r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a real number $r$ between $0$ and $1$ and two points $P=(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ in the plane, find the coordinates in terms of $r$ of the point $T$ on segment $PQ$ such that $PT/PQ = r$.

Let $T=(x_3,y_3)$

$\frac{PT}{PQ} = \frac{\sqrt{(x_1-x_3)^2+(y_1-y_3)^2}}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}} = r$

$(x_1-x_3)^2+(y_1-y_3)^2 = r^2(x_1-x_2)^2+r^2(y_1-y_2)^2$

This is where, I get stuck. Going further, I can't quite see how to manipulate the equation to define $T$ in terms of $r$. Playing around with the equation I just get a pretty scary non-linear equation.

Comment: Hint: $x_3$ divides the segment $x_1x_2$ in the same ratio as $T$ divides $PQ$.

Comment: this may help - https://doubleroot.in/lessons/coordinate-geometry-basics/section-formula/

Comment: @dxiv using similarity, if we let $T = (x,y) $ then $x= r(x_2-x_1) + x_1$ and $y = r(y_2-y_1)+y_1$

Comment: @Edmund That's correct, and it's the easiest way to derive those formulas.